# Silverlight - Button control tab stop twice mystery

Tags: silverlight, tabs, keyboard-events

I'm debugging a large Silverlight application and i'm finding on every form all button controls receive tab focus twice before going to next control. I cannot reproduce this behavior in a simple hello world application though. Interestingly this problem does not occur on HyperlinkButton controls in the same form, just Button. Any idea what would cause this, or some things to help me isolate the cause of this?

Thanks in advance.

**[Edit]**

If I set the IsTabStop property to false then it just tabs on the button one time. I hesitate to use this as a fix as I really would like to know what the source of the problem is.

I've traced the problem to the Implicit button style that we're using in a resource file. I would really like to know why this XAML causes this to happen.

**Implicit Button Style XAML**

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextContentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,3" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
<Grid x:Name="grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition From="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="-2"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="Pressed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="0"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.01" To="MouseOver">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="7"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Normal">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BaseColor2}"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1.0" KeySpline="0,0,0.0299999993294477,0.920000016689301"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="1.05"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="1.05"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BaseColor2}"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.75"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.3"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" >
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.0" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border x:Name="BaseBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" >
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BaseColor7}"/>
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalInnerBorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
            <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" Opacity="0" Background="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" Margin="-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5"/>
            <Border x:Name="PressedBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" Background="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-1">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="2" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusedBrush}" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" /> <!--IsHitTestVisible="false"-->
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This happens because the first focus is on the TextBlock within the button, the second focus is the button, the reason it even focuses on the TextBlock is because you have a Template overwriting the default style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the `IsTabStop` property of the `ContentControl` in your template to False:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" IsTabStop="False" (...) />
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Is this an intentional behavior of Silverlight? I would really like to know the rational behind this or why it has to be done when setting default styles on buttons.

Comment: Your style is definitely not the default. The rationale here is that anything that derives from Control (including ContentControl) has IsTabStop=true by default, because in most cases you don't use other controls inside controls. Therefore you need to explicitly set it to false when you don't want to have a 2nd tab stop inside your template.

Comment: I had same issue with ContentControl, it had nothing to do with the style. Thanks robertos.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is something on your `Button`'s template that has `IsTabStop` set to true.

How complex is your template? Try resetting to the default template to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: We are using an implicit button style in a resource template file. I'll paste that code in my comment. If I remove this implicit button style it works perfectly, but the buttons no longer have the right look. How do I go about resetting the button's template?