# Tab twice to move over Silverlight ComboBox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am developing a Silverlight 4 out of browser application using a standard [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and I need to press the  **tab key twice** to move over the control. The other controls (TextBox, RadioButton etc) in the data entry form are all behaving normally, i.e. only a single tab is required.

I created a simple sample application and found that the ComboBox was behaving correctly so there is something special about my real application that is causing the problem. I suspect the problem is due to the fact that I am using the [AccentColor Theme](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/themes/accent.html). I've had a number of problems with these themes and have come to realise that they should be considered as samples of what is possible. Their quality is not good enough for use in a production application as this [Introducing the new Silverlight 4 themes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/esthetique/archive/2010/08/19/introducing-the-new-silverlight-4-themes.aspx) blog post suggests.

I am asking this question so that I can answer it myself to capture the solution for future reference.

Comment: Just found a duplication question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061821/silverlight-button-control-tab-stop-twice-mystery so this should probably be deleted.

Comment: After paying a bit more attention, this other question is about a Button rather than a ComboBox so perhaps it shouldn't be considered a duplicate even though the source of the problem (custom implicit styles) is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The [AccentColor Theme](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/themes/accent.html) creates an [implicit Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for a ComboBox which includes setting the Template property. This template uses a [ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with a custom style that wraps the [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) inside a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for some reason (styling?) and by default the [IsTabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property is true. Explicitly setting this property to false restores the intuitive behaviour of a single tab to move over the control.

```
<ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Center" IsTabStop="False">
  <ContentControl.Foreground>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ContentPresenterWrapperColor" Color="{StaticResource BaseColor1}" />
  </ContentControl.Foreground>
  <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</ContentControl>
```

The standard ComboBox template does not include this [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which explains the difference in behaviour. I am not familiar enough with the AccentColor theme to know if it would be better to remove the ContentControl altogether or if it is required for the custom visual styling.

FYI [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy) was a great help in tracking down the problem in the behaviour, even if it is a bit pricey imho :-)